What Letter Am I Hiding?
To which letter is this cryptic text referring?

I , USING NINES  HAVE SHROUDED IT UNITY ADD INVERT I AM HTS Q YW  CPT TBUGTS

Hint:

 The extra spaces in some places, as well as the single punctuation mark, are significant.


Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!
